# \hfill if possible, new line otherwise

Tags: spacing, alignment

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\setmarks[1]{\hfill (#1 marks)}
\begin{document}

This works well, text appears on right \setmarks{10}

On the other hand, this line with additional text gets broken on a new line \setmarks{10}

I prefer the additional text to appear on an separate line, still flushed to the right like the following:

%%%%
On the other hand, this line with additional text gets broken on a new line

\setmarks{10}
%%%%
\end{document}
```

How do I change the definition of `setmarks` so that the additional line is added automatically when needed?

Comment: Related/Duplicate?: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130473/measuring-line-length-using-hfill-to-justify-text-wrapping-and-right-justifyi

Comment: I have confirmed that both of the solutions at the above cited answer work for the MWE you have provided.  Shall we mark your question as a duplicate?